# ABP Login/Registration page in Angular UI instead of Identity Server UI

Tags: authentication, identityserver4, abp

How to integrate login/registration pages in angular project?

When I run the angular project and click on Login Page, it redirect to the Identity Server URL. We need to use the same domain where our Angular project is hosted. We are also using Volo.Account npm package in angular project so login page should be served by https://localhost:4200/account/login url.

I read the documentations and articles but no article found to integrate login in Angular UI.

Here is the article to customize the login page for MVC razor page and we need to customize the login page for Angular.
https://community.abp.io/articles/how-to-customize-the-login-page-for-mvc-razor-page-applications-9a40f3cd

ABP Framework version: 4.4.0
UI type: Angular
DB provider: EF Core
Tiered (MVC) or Identity Server Separated (Angular): yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution from the below URL.

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/Angular/Authorization#resource-owner-password-flow

Thanks
Imrankhan

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using ASP.NET to serve an API for your Angular frontend that is somehow secured by Identity Server.

In that case, you should create a `AuthController` with `Login` and `Logout` endpoints that will be called by a view you just normally implement in Angular. You can use JWT for authentication on subsequent API calls. https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/apis.html, e.g. a JSON token will be returned by the login endpoint.